# VS2010 C code - String pooling

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, winapi

Below code crash in VS 2010 when you compile with following flag and if you add /GF- or remove the opimization flag they don't crash. The crash occur at assembly code which translate 'if( path[i] == '/' )'. I like to understand the optimization that compiler does here and lead to crash. Looking forward for some pointers.

-Karthik

`cl.exe /MD /O2 test.c`

`//` Test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include  <string.h>

void testpath(char* path, int bufsiz)  
{  

    int i;  

    printf("%p\n", path);  
    for( i=0; i < strlen(path); i++ ) {  
      if( path[i] == '/' ) {  
         path[i] = '\\';  
     }  
  }  
}

int main()  
{  

    const char* path = "testexport.prj";  
    char *path1 = "testexport.prj";  
    printf("%p\n", path);  
    printf("%p\n", path1);  
    testpath(path, 1024);  
}
```

Comment: You say this crashes. Is there any additional information given saying why it crashes? The code you show shouldn't have any trouble. As you say, the conditional should prevent the assignment from executing because there is no `'/'` character in the `path` that you pass to the function. Are you sure that the code you're showing here is an exact copy of the code that you are running?

Answer (score 7):

Trying to modify the contents of a `string literal` invokes Undefined Behaviour.

From ISO C99 (`Section 6.4.5/6`)

> It  is  unspeciﬁed  whether  these  arrays  are  distinct  provided  their  elements  have  the appropriate  values.  **If  the  program  attempts  to  modify  such  an  array,  the  behavior  is undeﬁned**

From ISO C++-98 (`Section 2.13.4/2`)

> Whether all string literals are distinct(that is, are stored in non overlapping objects) is implementation defined. **The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.**

On most implementations (including MSVC) this results to crash of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand modifying 'string' literal leads to unspecified behavior. But my point why an optimized build lead to crash when the string literal doesn't get modified due to conditional check 'path[i] == '/'' in the code. Can you please comment about it?

Comment: @Kartlee: path[i] = '\\'; tries to modify the contents of the string literal and this leads to crash of your application and yes the behavior is undefined.(not unspecified). :) The conditional check is just fine IMHO.

Comment: It is a real surprise when string literal which doesn't enter the code which modify it due to conditional check will lead to crash. Did you get a chance to see the assembly code what exactly happens here? If you turn off string pooling, they don't lead to crash. I suspect if the compiler does any lookahead to check if string literal gets modified when string pooling is turned on.

Answer (score 5):

You try to modify a string literal, that's undefined behavior.

```
 const char* path = "testexport.prj";
 testpath(path, 1024);
 // then later:
 void testpath(char* path, int bufsiz)
 {
     int i;  
     for( i=0; i`<`strlen(path); i++ ) {  
     if( path[i] == '/' ) {  
         path[i] = '\\';// <<<<<< UB here
     }  
 }
```

string literals are usually stored in read-only memory, so on your implementation an attempt to modify a string literal results in access violation that crashes your program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand modifying 'string' literal leads to unspecified behavior. But my point why an optimized build lead to crash when the string literal doesn't get modified due to conditional check 'path[i] == '/'' in the code. Can you please comment about it?

Comment: @Kartlee: When optimization is on you can't be sure which line you're on when you debug, so the most likely explanation is that you misinterpret the results of the debug session. To be sure modify the if-statement: `if( path[i] == '/' ) { printf( "gonna modify\n" );          path[i] = '\\';  } so that there's a debug print before a modification attempt. I'm pretty sure the program will crash exactly after the modification attempt.

Comment: But in the code he's shown, there is no `'/'` character in the `path` that he passes to the function. So either there's a really odd bug in the compiler, or there's something he's not telling us.

Answer (score -1):

We have an application where in VC6.0 there appears to be a bug in string pooling.  Two different strings appear to "pool" to one string, causing a crash.  This crash does not occur in VS2010.  OR if /Zi is used in VS6.0 instead of /ZI.  Just wondering if the default in VS6.0 is to use string pooling and not the default in VS2010. In which case it could be that the string pooling bug still exists.  If there are MANY strings which are near identical, the working theory I have (yet to be vetted) is that there is a hash collision going undetected in the string pooling, which eliminates one of the two strings.  This would be visible in the generated ASM code when looking at the pointers for two nearly similar strings.
In our case we are not modifying strings in VC6.0, just referencing them.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10887694)

Comment: I need to share a case  We have a large customer base, and over 12+ years using VS6.0 C++, I have seen two instances of applications sensitive to string pooling.  We create objects with a ->name value. We provide a "find_object("String")" API to search for objects by name.  With string pooling two cases have been observed where object "StringA" and "StringB" are both created and exist, but Object "StringB" cannot be found with a search as it's string object was optimized so it doesn't match the original string.  The generated *.asm shows the string optimized away.  TBD sanitize so I can share.