# C++: Mapping __file__ to predefined number

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

This seems impossible to me, but StackOverflow has solved things that seemed impossible to me before, so here it goes:

I have a predefined mapping between filenames and ids, I would like to be able to map `__FILE__` to it's id at compile time if at all possible.

Sorry for the shoddy explanation, I hope an example helps:

Ids generated before the compilation process starts through some script:

```
#define _FILE_IDS_MAIN_CPP 1
#define _FILE_IDS_HELPER_CPP 2
#define _FILE_IDS_HELPER_HPP 3
```

In the code I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
printf("%d", GET_FILEID_MACRO(__file__));
```

Comment: Can you give an example of code you'd like to be able to write?

Comment: @sftrabbit Added an example. Sorry I wasn't more clear

Comment: Does it have to be at compile-time?

Comment: You need C++11 and [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Unfortunately I am working with C++98. Constexpr are not possible.

Comment: Then you can't manipulate strings at compile time, sorry.

Comment: @JorenHeit If I can't figure out how to do it at compile time I will probably fall back on some kind of hash map to get the values through the strings, but I'd much prefer having things ready at compile time.

Comment: @Afiefh Hmm yeah I was trying to cook up something that would do the trick but I was already using C++11 features like `constexpr` and `operator""`. Are you sure you can't use those?

Comment: also you tagged this as C++ and are clearly using C.

Comment: @zoska Actually I'm using C++98, which is important for this question because template metaprogramming might help solve this. I know printf is C-style but it was just an example.

Comment: I'd suggest you to tweak your build system to define file IDs using command-line switches (like `-DCUR_ID=1`).

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, you can probably use `constexpr` functions, available since C++11, to perform some computation on the file name characters. For example, if you simply let the string length be your ID, you could have:

```
template <unsigned int N>
constexpr unsigned int FileID(char const (&a)[N])
{
    // your computation goes here
    return N;
}

#include <iostream>
template <unsigned int N> void print()
{
    std::cout << "Static value: " << N << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    print<FileID(__FILE__)>();
}
```

The `print` template is included as proof that the number is computed at compile time.

Taking this as a starting point, you could change `FileID` into some kind of hash function, or perhaps into a static map lookup - this is certainly possible, though probably fairly verbose. I'm sure someone has done it already, though.

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but wouldn't that map all files with the same name length to the same ID? Also I'm stick with C++98 so I don't get C++11 goodness :-(

Comment: @Afiefh: Yes. That's why I said it's a starting point that needs to be worked on. (Unless you're creating PHP, in which case you're done.)

Answer (score 0):

Having C++11:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

constexpr unsigned id(const char* file) {
    return (std::strcmp(file, "One") == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<unsigned>
void print() {
    std::cout << "Zero\n";
}

template<>
void print<1>() {
    std::cout << "One\n";
}

int main () {
    print<id("Zero")>();
    print<id("One")>();
    return 0;
}
```

Being unsure if strcmp is valid in a constexpr function and following the second answer in the link from @MSalters:

```
#include <iostream>

// Code from @Robert Mason
// =======================

constexpr bool static_strequal_helper(const char * a, const char * b, unsigned len) {
   return (len == 0) ? true : ((*a == *b) ? static_strequal_helper(a + 1, b + 1, len - 1) : false);
}

template <unsigned N1, unsigned N2>
constexpr bool static_strequal(const char (&str1)[N1], const char (&str2)[N2]) {
   return (N1 == N2) ? static_strequal_helper(&(str1[0]), &(str2[0]), N1) : false;
}

// End


template <unsigned N>
constexpr unsigned id(const char (&file)[N]) {
    return (static_strequal(file, "One")) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<unsigned>
void print() {
    std::cout << "Zero\n";
}

template<>
void print<1>() {
    std::cout << "One\n";
}

int main () {
    print<id("Zero")>();   // Prints Zero
    print<id("One")>();    // Prints One
    print<id(__FILE__)>(); // Prints Zero - Is __FILE__ always an array?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice, is that guaranteed to work by the standard?

Comment: No, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144118/c-compare-two-string-literals

Answer (score 0):

> I have a predefined mapping between filenames and ids, I would like to be able to map **FILE** to it's id at compile time if at all possible.

The information comes from outside. That is not a job for C preprocessor - it's a job for accommodating build system integrated with the project. In the build system, for each compiled file, query the "mapping" database for id and add a `FILEID=<the queried id>` macro definition. For example using CMake, that I am comfortable with, I could:

```
==> CMakeLists.txt <==
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test)
file(GLOB srcs *.c)

set(map
  file1.c  123
  file2.c  234
  main.c   345
)

foreach(ff IN LISTS srcs)
  # Find ff in the mapping
  set(file "")
  set(fileid "")
  foreach(id IN LISTS map)
    if(file STREQUAL "")
      set(file ${id})
      continue()
    endif()
    get_filename_component(filename ${ff} NAME)
    message("${filename} ${file}")
    if(filename STREQUAL file)
      set(fileid ${id})
    endif()
    set(file "")
  endforeach()
  if(NOT fileid STREQUAL "")
    set_source_files_properties(${ff} PROPERTIES
      COMPILE_DEFINITIONS FILEID=${fileid}
    )
  endif()
endforeach()

add_executable(test ${srcs})
add_test(NAME test COMMAND test)


==> file1.c <==
const int file1 = FILEID;

==> file2.c <==
const int file2 = FILEID;

==> main.c <==
#include <stdio.h>
extern const int file1, file2;
int main() {
    printf("%d %d\n", file1, file2);
}
```

which will compile the file with:

```
[1/4] /usr/bin/cc -DFILEID=123 ... /file1.c
[2/4] /usr/bin/cc -DFILEID=234 ... /file2.c
[3/4] /usr/bin/cc -DFILEID=345 ... /main.c
```

In the same way you could configure your build system to pre-process your file with something more powerful than C, you could use python, php and m4. Assuming you have a fluent build system, this seems like one of simplest way to solve such problems.