# Why doesn't this program work for inputs larger than 25 chars?

Tags: c, pointers

This is the program working well for input: `"problem"`

but stops for: `"this is the problem,this is the problem,this is the problem"`

**Why?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p;
    gets(p);
    puts(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any memory protection issue?

Comment: This is UB, you didn't allocate any memory. p is pointing to nothing. Also, this is C not C++.

Comment: but then how small strings are scanned without problem...what is problem with larger one..please explain if you know...

Comment: Undefined behavior, I guess!

Comment: @user2725368 As I said this is Undefined Behavior, which means what happens is undefined. Anything can happen.

Comment: `gets()` isn't C anymore, you shouldn't be using it anyway. And it's `int main(void)`.

Comment: You can also use `malloc` to allocate memory to pointer `*p`.

Comment: To better understand what other comments describe as undefined behavior you may see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420753/unspecified-undefined-and-implementation-defined-behavior-wiki-for-c/18420754#18420754).

Answer (score 6):

You are missing to allocate memory, to read the data into using `gets()`, as `char * p` is just a pointer, pointing to a random address.

This provoke undefined behaviour. Anything could happen, even when read in only 1 character.

The fact, that the program does not crash for less then 26 characters is just bad luck.

You can provide memory by for example changing

```
char * p;
```

to be

```
char str[42] = {0}; /* = {0} initializes the array to all `0`s. */
char * p = str;
```

As per *urzeit*'s comment: This makes p point to an array of 42 characters, which itself is capabale to hold a so called "string" of 41 characters. The 42nd character is resevered to hold the `0`-terminator, that indicates the "string"'s end.

---

**Note**: `gets()` is evil, as the programmer has no possibility to tell the function how much characters the buffer passed to `gets()` is capabale to hold. Use `fgets()` instead.

---

Btw: `int main(void)` ought to `return` an `int`.

Comment: Additional information: In this example strings up to a length of 41 (plus the 0-char terminating the string) can be stored in the memory address p. If the string is longer, this will still be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Technically `main()` doesn't *have* to explicitly return, but I agree with you that it *ought* to. +1 for "bad luck" that it "does not crash".

Comment: main() have to return explicitily. if you not explicitly return int, it will return the last function call return : here, it's puts returned value

Comment: @0xBAADF00D: `main()` will return `0` implicitly if you don't provide it. It's the only function for which that is true.

Comment: @ urzeit u are right ..char str[4];
char * p = str;  can accept string having length 12.....

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, please check by your self. I'have tested this on Debian 7 with GCC 4.7. It's not new, since many year, gcc return the last value on the top os the stack if you not specidy return value on main()

Comment: @0xBAADF00D: Please check the C standard, your compiler is no authority on correct C. Section 5.1.2.2.3 clearly says that "reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of `0`".

Comment: @PaulGriffiths anyway, this is a false debate. if the prototype requires INT: return an INT. In C99 "default int" has been removed

Comment: @0xBAADF00D: I just quoted from C11. You can read it yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths How, i see, you use g++ to compile .c file (very very very bad practive) ?  I 'have test with g++ main return 0, but if you use cc ou gcc, main return the last returned value...

Comment: @0xBAADF00D: I've already answered that. g++ is a C++ compiler, by the way. gcc correctly returns zero if you use it properly.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths  this question have "C" tags not "C++"

Comment: @0xBAADF00D this is the excerpt from C99 draft standard (WG14/N1256) Paul already told you about: 

**5.1.2.2.3 Program termination.

If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the
initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value
returned by the main function as its argument; reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0. [...]**

Comment: @0xBAADF00D Use `gcc -std=c99` to compile according to the C99 standard. GCC's default is c89+extensions and is quite obsolete. It is kept because moving to C99 changes the behavior of some defined programs, and it is difficult to tell what old code would be broken, see for instance http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/01/20/Constants-quiz and http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/01/20/Constants-quiz-answers (but we are getting off-topic here).

Answer (score 3):

The actual reality is that it's probably "working" for short strings because you're just overwriting your stack, which is memory your program owns, so it doesn't crash. However, this is not "working" by any reasonable definition of the word.

From a C language point of view, all you know is that it's just undefined behavior, it's bad, and you should fix it.

Comment: The stack is not your data segment.

Comment: o sorry .. ya stack too ... what factor fixes the stck size??

Comment: The stack size is not relevant. You could have a 4TB stack, you'll still overrun it if you start writing a few bytes down from the top.

Comment: but plz answer my question .. does every  program hase same stck size .. whtz the depending factor??

Comment: @user2725368: The specific stack size is irrelevant, the code is badly formed and trying to reason about its behavior is a waste of time.

Comment: means os .. well i am not satisfied at all .. may be you are r8 ... i hope so too... but i have week concepts in compiler issues .. btw thanx.

Comment: +1 for looking at a different point of view generally neglected :)