# Swapping Output Lines making the program buggy (pointers)

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *addition(int a, int b);

int result;
int *result_ptr;

int *addition(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a + b;
    int *d = &c;

    return d;
}

int main(void)
{
    result = *(addition(1,2));  
    result_ptr = addition(1,2);

    printf("result = %d\n", result); //outputline1
    printf("result_ptr = %d\n", *result_ptr); //outputline2

    return 0;
}
```

If it is complied and processed as the current code is written, result_ptr gives weird values. However, if you swap 2 output lines it doesn't. Why does it do that?

Comment: *Both* `result` and `result_ptr` are based on the address of a local-scope variable in `addition()` that is not in-scope when that address is used for evaluation. This is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the address of the local variable `c`. This is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420753/unspecified-undefined-and-implementation-defined-behavior-wiki-for-c/18420754#18420754). That is, your program is erroneous and this means that it has no obligation to show a predictable or sane behavior. Changing the position of the two `printf` gives you another erroneous program, which (again) is not required to behave correctly or coherently with the previous erroneous program.

**EDIT** (adding relevant citations from C99 draft standard N1256 - emphasis mine)

> #### 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators
>
> [...]
>
> **Semantics**
>
> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
>   a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
>   object. If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. **If an
>   invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is
>   undefined.**<sup>87)</sup>

(footnote #87)

> Thus, `&*E` is equivalent to `E` (even if `E` is a null pointer), and `&(E1[E2])` to `((E1)+(E2))`. It is always true that if E is a function designator or an lvalue that is a valid operand of the unary `&` operator, `*&E` is a function designator or an lvalue equal to `E`. If `*P` is an lvalue and `T` is the name of an object pointer type, `*(T)P` is an lvalue that has a type compatible with that to which `T` points.
>
> Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, ***and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.***

The relevant sentence is the last one (emphasis mine): the `c` local variable has already ended its lifetime by the time when its address, which was returned by the `addition` function, is dereferenced in `main`.