# Using int to print character constants

Tags: c, int

I wrote the following program,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int i='A';
printf("i=%c",i);
return 0;
}
```

and I got the result as,

```
i=A
```

So I tried another program,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int i='ABC';
printf("i=%c",i);
return 0;
}
```

According to me, since 32 bits are used to store an int value and each of 'A', 'B' and 'C' have 8 bit ASCII codes which totals to 24 bits therefore 24 bits were stored in a 32 bit unit. So I expected the output to be,

```
i=ABC
```

but the output instead was

```
i=C
```

and I can't understand why?

Comment: `"%c"` will never print 3 characters.

Comment: Did you turn on the compiler warnings? Did your compiler not cry __at all__?

Comment: The 'A' notation is for specifying a single character. 'ABC' is 3 characters, what happens when you specify more than 1 character in a a character literal notation is non-standard and will depend on your particular compiler. What happens could also be undefined behavior. However - you should tell us which compiler you use.

Comment: read the warnings. They'll tell you about the [multi-character constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7755202/995714) https://stackoverflow.com/q/6944730/995714

Comment: @Useless C does not specify any _character literal_.  `'ABC'` is an _integer character constant_, one containing more than one character.

Comment: @nos The C standard specifies code like `'ABC'` as an _integer character constant_.  It _is_ standard.   The value it represents is is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

'ABC' in this case is a integer character constant as per section **6.4.4.4.10** of the standard.

> An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer
>   character constant containing a single character that maps to a
>   single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
>   representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. The
>   value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g.,'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a single-byteexecution character, is
>   implementation-defined. If an integer character constant contains a
>   single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results
>   when an object with type char whose value is that of the single
>   character or escape sequence is converted to type int.

In this case, `'A'==0x41`, `'B'==0x42`, `'C'==0x43`, and *your* compiler then interprets `i` to be `0x414243`. As said in the other answer, this value is implementation dependent.

When you try to access it using `'%c'`, the overflown part will be cut and you are only left with `0x43`, which is `'C'`.

To get more insight to it, read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461862/print-decimal-value-of-a-char) as well.

Comment: Technically it is _not_ non-standard... it does is implementation dependent but it clearly is part of the standard. see section [6.4.4.4.10](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: The standard doesn't specify those values for A, B, and C either

Comment: Thank you. I am happy that I can always learn something from SO not just when I ask questions but also when I answer questions.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion specifier `c` used in this call

```
printf("i=%c",i);
```

in fact extracts one character from the integer argument. So using this specifier you in any case can not get three characters as the output.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> c If no l length modifier is present, the int argument is converted to
>   an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written

Take into account that the internal representation of a multi-byte character constant is implementation defined.  From the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10. ...The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape
>       sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
>       **implementation-defined**.

Answer (score 1):

`'ABC'` is an *integer character constant*.  Depending on code set (overwhelming it is ASCII), endian, `int` width (apparently 32 bits in OP's case), it may have the same value like below.  It is implementation defined behavior.

```
'ABC'
0x41424300
0x434241
or others.
```

The `"%c"` directs `printf()` to take the `int` value, cast it to `unsigned char` and print the associated character.  This is the main reason for apparent loss of information.

In OP's case, it appears that `i` took on the value of 0x434241.

```
int i='A';
printf("i=%c",i); --> 'A'
// same as 
printf("i=%c",0x434241); --> 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, `'A'` is an `int` *constant* that's guaranteed to fit into a `char`.

`'ABC'` is a *multicharacter constant*. It has an `int` type, but an *implementation defined* value. The behaviour on using `%c` to print that in `printf` is possibly *undefined* if the value cannot fit into a `char`.

Comment: @chux: Yes it's not the first time you've called me out on my sloppy terminology; in this area particularly.

Comment: `printf` will expect an `int` parameter to match the `%c` format specifier, and will convert the `int` value to an `unsigned char` value. None of that is undefined behaviour, but the output will be implementation defined because the `int` value is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

if you want i to contain 3 characters you need to init a array that contains 3 characters

`char i[3];
i[0]= 'A';
i[1]= 'B';
i[2]='C';`

the ' ' can contain only one char your code converts the integer i into a character or better you store in your 32 bit intiger a converted 8 bit character. But i think You want to seperate the 32 bits into 8 bit containers make a char array like char i[3]. and then you will see that

```
int j=i;
```

this will result in an error because you are unable to convert a char array into a integer.